# quickfix/j problem with receive message

Tags: java, quickfix

I've problem with QuickFixJ Application. I create object of class(AppImpl) which implements Appplication interface, pass it to SocketAcceptor and wait for messages. However I receive new messages from client(I can see them in logs) I cannot work with them! From all overrided methods in AppImpl only one and only once was invoked by SocketAcceptor - onCreate.
What could caused this problem?

Example from my logs:

Logon:

<20110829-05:35:56, FIX.4.4:localhost->localhost, incoming> (8=FIX.4.49=5835=A49=localhost56=localhost34=8652=20110829-05:35:5610=250)

<20110829-05:35:56, FIX.4.4:localhost->localhost, event> (Accepting session FIX.4.4:localhost->localhost from /127.0.0.1:57179)

But method:

```
@Override
public void onLogon(SessionID arg0) {
    System.out.println("On logon");

}
```

Wasn't performed.

Comment: What message types appear in your logs as being received from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just wondering why your SenderCompID and TargetCompID are same? Both are "localhost".

Comment: Cause I run client and server on the same computer.

Comment: Even if you run the acceptor and initiator on the same machine, you must use different SenderCompID and TargetCompID between acceptor and initiator. The combination of these IDs identify a FIX session between two parties.